# Linearity of Integrals over Infinite Series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, continuity

I have a question concerning the linearity of definite integrals of infinite series representations of Real functions. I only have a cursory understanding of the proper terminology and theory and will do my best to define the question correctly. If I fail at any point, please advise and I will edit accordingly.

Consider a Real-valued function $f(x)$ that can be expressed using the infinite series:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty g_n(x)
$$
Where $g_n(x)$ is continuous for all $n$, and the series is convergent over $a \leq x \leq b$

Here, if  $a \leq c \leq d \leq b$ and if $h(x)$ is continuous over $ c \leq x \leq d$ then under what conditions does the following hold?

$$
\int_c^d f(x)h(x) \:dx = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \:\int_c^d h(x)g_n(x) \:dx
$$

Thank you!

Comment: When you say, "the series is convergent", what do you mean?  Are you familiar with the distinction between pointwise and uniform convergence?

Comment: @JacobManaker - I'm not overly familiar unfortunately, to take an example, consider $$\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n$$ which is convergent for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. 

Here, when I say convergent, I'm referring to that. 

My apologies if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Is $h$ related to $f$ in any way? It seems more natural that $h = 1$. Look up Fubini's theorem and Tonelli's theorem for interchanging integrals (summation is an integral with respect to counting measure).

Comment: Where did $h$ pop in from?

Comment: @Mason - Yes indeed, I meant 
$$
\int_c^d f(x)h(x) \:dx
$$

I have edited accordingly.  Thanks for your comment re Fubini's Theorem and Tonelli's. I will inspect.

Comment: @copper.hat - Sorry, I had made an error. I have edited to correct

Comment: The integration of $f(x)$ and interchanging sum with integral in the right hand side is valid for uniformly convergent series (such as power series and some Fourier series). But I have to ask you what would be the motivation to integrate $f(x) \; h(x)$? Maybe I can think of an application for a Laplace transform, but I needded to ask you this first.